# How to ScrollDown nested scroll bar to the bottom of the nested scroll div on button click in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, scroll, nested

I have one scrollbar section(Nested) in my page ,i want to send scrollbar to the bottom of its section a button click but i am unable to do anything with the inner scrollbar. I tried almost every method but they move the main window scroll bar.
Help me in solving this.

Below is the sample code(Only for Reference)

```
<div class="scroll-box" id="scrollDiv">
<button (click)="SomeFunction()"> click here to navigate to bottom </button>
<h1> hello </h1>
<h1> Hi</h1> 
<h1> hello </h1> 
<h1> Hi</h1>
<p id="content"> BOTTOM </p>
</div>
```

P.S: SomeFunction() method includes all the code to send the scrollbar to the bottom of the page.
Edit:
All methods i tried

```
//var elmnt = document.getElementById("scrollDiv");
//var EsignHeight = elmnt.scrollHeight;
//var contentHeight = document.getElementById('scrollDiv').clientHeight;
//window.parent.scrollTo(0,100);
//window.parent.scroll({ left: 0, top: 500, behavior: 'smooth' });
//this.content.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'start' });
//this.scrollObject.target.scrollTop = -100;
//var newEsignHeight=-EsignHeight;
//window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector("#container").scrollHeight);
//$("elmnt").scrollTop(100);
//   console.log("prining offset");
//var Content=document.getElementById(content);
//var topPos = Content.offsetTop;
//document.getElementById(scrollDiv).scrollTop = topPos;
//document.getElementById('scrollDiv').scrollTop = topPos-100;
//   console.log("offsetTop 1:",elmnt.offsetTop);
//   var tempScrollDiv= document.getElementById('scrollDiv');
//   console.log("offsetTop 1:",tempScrollDiv.offsetTop);
//   //tempScrollDiv.scrollTop=0;
//   //var topPos= elmnt.offsetTop;
//  // tempScrollDiv.scrollTop=topPos-elmnt.offsetTop;
//   console.log("offsetTop 2:",elmnt.offsetTop);
//   //$(tempScrollDiv).animate({scrollTop:$(tempScrollDiv).scrollTop() + ($('content').offset().top-$(tempScrollDiv).offset().top)});
```

More Info: On click of button i want send to scroll bar to the paragraph

**This Scrollbar is Nested that means i want to do movement in the child scroll bar not the main window scroll bar**

Comment: please show what you have tried yet

Comment: i have added methods which i have tried , Please refer the question again.

Comment: please clearify your need more. either by images,html, or simple explaining etc

Comment: on click of the button i want to move the scroll bar to the <p> tag or bottom of the page( As p tag is in the bottom) ,Please check question again for more info.
Notice: i want to move the child scroll bar not the window scroll bar(Main).

Comment: ok.. use <a href="#id_to_which_you_want_to_move"> in place of button

Comment: you want to scroll your page to that position ???

Comment: yes but not the main page. i want to scroll within that particular div( id="scrollDiv" ). i hope you are getting what i am trying to say.

Comment: on using href , my page gets reloaded(refresh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated some part of your code and it started working fine:

```
<div class="scroll-box" id="scrollDiv">
    <button (click)="someFunction(bottomPara)"> click here to navigate to bottom </button>
    <h1> hello </h1>
    <h1> Hi</h1> 
    <h1> hello </h1> 
    <h1> Hi</h1>
    <div #bottomPara>
        <p id="content"> BOTTOM </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your typescript file add following function:

```
someFunction(bottomPara){
    bottomPara.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Changes to your code:

1. Added div before P element and gave it ID as bottomPara.
2. passing that object to your someFunction method in button element.
3. Calling scrollIntoView method of passed input.

Hope this works for you.
Here is the plunker link: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/rM2v06dxN9vDKhrb?preview

Comment: Hey Vikram thanks for your solution and sorry for the incomplete code i have shown in the question. i saw your plunker code and its working properly but for the window scroll bar(i.e main scroll bar), In my case i have child scroll bar(that is small scroll bar inside main window). I want movement within that small scrollbar div section.

Comment: Hi @RoshanSingh, I updated my plunker.
Now I have two scroll bars:
1. Main Scroll bar
2. Small Scroll bar inside main div.

When you click button, Small scroll bar scroll down to bottom of inner scroll bar.
Please check if this help: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/rM2v06dxN9vDKhrb?preview

Answer (score 0):

look at this once. It can be done by html simply. You have to specify the div height and overflow to scroll and here is the a example. Its the basic example what I understand from your question

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<div style="background-color:red; overflow:scroll;height:500px;" >
<a href="#bottom">Clock to go to bottom of div</a>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p><p id="bottom">This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey Adesh, thanks for your time. your answer is correct but for main window scroll bar. i want to move the child scroll bar to the bottom or to a particular id.

Comment: just click outside the div and scroll it will scroll the main window then.. for example in the snippet i have given, scroll in between div's and main window scrollers then the main page scroller will work

Comment: thanks alot, that works but if i want to scroll to an element which appears only after  the button click. in that case <a href > will not get the id of that element.

Comment: if you want to go to the next element then you can follow the same. if the content is large scrolling will be visible else the element is visible

Comment: will it be able to get the id of the element which appears after button is clicked(on ngIf)? before button is clicked it will be hidden.

Comment: is my answer not satisfy you

Comment: yeah, it is satisfactory.

Comment: i did, but it will be not displayed publicaly because of  the policy of stack overflow, where they do not allow user with less than n reputation to upvote.