# Two separate scroll areas simple solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a specific layout I'm trying to accomplish using simple HTML5 and CSS, with as little jQuery/JS as possible as the site has to be high performing and light.

In this site, I have two separate scroll areas. When the user first starts scrolling down, **scroll area 1** scrolls down and the **fixed content area** stays fixed to the right of it. When the user reaches the end of that **scroll 1 area**, the scroll continues as normal on the body of the document (i.e **scroll area 2**) where the **fixed content area** is no longer visible and the site just keeps going down as it should. I've seen this in a multitude of sites but I just can't figure out what is called or how people accomplish it.

So again, we scroll down through **area 1** until there is no more content to display there, while **fixed content area** stays put and visible to the right, and then the scrolling continues through **scroll area 2**, where we no longer have to display the fixed content.

Any tips, hints, ideas on how to get started?

Here is a picture to illustrate:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Look at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp to understand the logic of using onScroll event and adding/removing css classes. This is all you need to accomplish the above. And yes, jQuery is not much help here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52251485/how-to-scrolldown-nested-scroll-bar-to-the-bottom-of-the-nested-scroll-div-on-bu/52252480#52252480

Comment: @Twisty I believe a "where do I start" is a valid question in SO that does not require minimal code. It would have been nice to have a fiddle with 3-4 CSS classes and basic HTML included, but it is not strictly required, if someone fears to exclude different approaches.

Comment: @AlexPakka "*You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*" - https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @AlexPakka I think that a MCVE in this post would help identify the proper scope of the question and allow specific and thorough answer to be created. "Where do I start" with HTML? With CSS? With JS/jQuery? The answer could go all over. How does that help OP?

Comment: @Twisty I see your point. Let''s give the author a chance to improve. Otherwise I don't mind if it''s closed.

Comment: @AlexPakka agreed, also I see no votes to close yet.

Comment: I am obviously at a loss as to how to start. The answer below with the fiddle seems to do the trick, but I'm still interested in hearing more people's opinions about it.

Answer (score 3):

## Create a fixed sidebar restricted to a vertical section of the page

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('.Scroller').length) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var side = $('.Scroller');
      if ($(side).height() < window.innerHeight) {
        var top = $('.SectionWrap').offset().top,
          bottom = $('.SectionWrap').outerHeight() + top,
          maxY = bottom - $(side).outerHeight(),
          y = $(this).scrollTop() + 90; /*Extra padding for header menu*/
        if (y > top) { /*Scrolled past top of side bar*/
          if (y < maxY) { /*Scrolled past bottom of sidebar minus scroller height*/
            $(side).addClass('Active').removeAttr('style');
          } else {
            $(side).removeClass('Active').css({
              position: 'absolute',
              top: maxY - top - 10 + 'px' /*manual padding*/
            });
          }
        } else {
          $(side).removeClass('Active');
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #111;
  color: #aaa;
}

.PageWrap {
  display: flex;
}

.Section {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.SectionWrap {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #eee;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  /*Sidebar width*/
}

.Scroller {
  width: 200px;
}

.Scroller.Active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 90px;
  /*Match script*/
}

.SideContent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer {
  background: #111;
  height: 500px;
  /*Simulated*/
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #aaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>HEADER</h1>
</header>

<div class="PageWrap">

  <div class="PageContent">
    <div class="Section">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur a lectus eget quam viverra tempor. Integer erat est, condimentum non massa vel, porta rutrum purus. Pellentesque venenatis nulla augue, eu auctor tortor sollicitudin vitae. Maecenas
        hendrerit justo at urna malesuada, eu elementum nibh porta. Vivamus accumsan magna elementum diam dapibus, eleifend bibendum metus dictum. Nulla blandit finibus risus, vitae tincidunt purus rutrum sed. Etiam nec justo tincidunt, sollicitudin lorem
        eget, dapibus odio. Curabitur molestie ac quam in iaculis. Nullam id egestas lorem. Nam sit amet neque sapien. Maecenas volutpat ante ligula, in efficitur augue efficitur eu. Nam sed sapien velit. Mauris eu dapibus orci. Vivamus elit nisi, porta
        id eros eu, semper malesuada nulla. Mauris id interdum nisi. Quisque sit amet sagittis augue.</p>

      <p>Curabitur a finibus libero. Morbi ut velit vitae est placerat laoreet. Donec at quam vestibulum neque volutpat porta quis vitae elit. Vestibulum dignissim commodo placerat. Aenean volutpat nunc in dolor viverra, vel dapibus tortor porta. Ut posuere
        urna sed metus mattis, in hendrerit enim tempor. Quisque porta ex quam, ut rutrum neque ultrices sit amet. Donec dictum nisl sollicitudin, elementum est non, ornare nisl.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Section">
      <p>Nulla risus nunc, pharetra a odio a, dapibus pretium mauris. Phasellus placerat velit diam, nec aliquam augue iaculis eget. Quisque feugiat fringilla velit, quis rhoncus ex dignissim sed. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
        nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam mollis odio ac sapien laoreet aliquam. Curabitur euismod nibh lacus, ut fermentum ligula dictum quis. Maecenas auctor ex eros, ac commodo quam pharetra et. Nam fringilla sem sit amet ullamcorper hendrerit.
        Nulla facilisi. Morbi ut faucibus elit, vel mattis lorem. Sed mollis posuere gravida. Nunc sagittis sapien purus, non aliquet velit suscipit non. Sed ut orci fringilla, vehicula elit nec, rutrum nulla. Aenean cursus massa mi, eget laoreet quam
        aliquam sed. Duis eu pulvinar mauris. Curabitur ultrices vestibulum tellus, ac elementum orci dignissim ultrices.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="SectionWrap">
    <div class="Scroller">
      <div class="SideContent">
        SECTION SIDE BAR
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<footer>
  FOOTER
</footer>
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want to accomplish. Thanks for your answer! Do you think there would be an approach to the same effect that didn't use as much jQuery?

Comment: Yes. You can use pure Javascript if you wish. There isn't that much jQuery in there, I am sure you could easily convert it.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `position` property of the element that you want to be visible as you scroll through a particular section to `sticky`. [Per MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> A stickily positioned element is an element whose computed position value is sticky. It's treated as relatively positioned until its containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting top to value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" until meeting the opposite edge of its containing block.

*Be aware that this property value is not supported [in some browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20sticky)*

See the demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-gap: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.header, .footer {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: firebrick;
}
.header::after, .footer::after {
  content: attr(class);
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 300px 1fr;
  grid-gap: 50px;
}
.main__content {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: aqua;
  height: min-content;
  padding: 20px;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* This is the code that makes the .sidebar visible while you scroll through the .main element*/
.sidebar--sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
<main class="main">
  <aside class="sidebar sidebar--sticky">Hello I am the sidebar</aside>
  <section class="main__content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi, nisi perspiciatis labore minus at cumque eum aliquam harum voluptatem, suscipit vitae inventore iusto eaque animi similique quibusdam ratione reprehenderit? Fugit?</p>
  </section>
</main>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

It works like this, the `.sidebar` and `.main__content` elements are both direct children of the `.main` element and the height of this element is defined by the height of it's children, in this case the `.main__content` element has a height of double the veiwport height and since the value of the `position` property of the `.sidebar` is `sticky` it will stay fixed in view until it reaches the bottom of it's containing block which is the `.main` element.

Comment: I like this solution because it is written purely in CSS. However, the lorem ipsum text on the left should travel down with the scroll, as the solution in jQuery presented above. Would CSS be able to accomplish that behavior?

Comment: When you say _" the lorem ipsum text on the left should travel down with the scroll"_, if I understand what you mean the text would scroll with the `sticky` content it is just that in the demo there is not enough content to show this. I have updated the code example to make it clear.